# Oracle XML Extract method - Requirement for Table Alias

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I'm having a strange issue where a query will work absolutely fine with a table alias but it doesn't when there isn't one.

So, this works as it should:

```
select a.xml.extract('(//test/@id)[1]').getStringVal() from test_table a;
```

Whereas, this does not work:

```
select xml.extract('(//test/@id)[1]').getStringVal() from test_table;
```

Error:

```
ORA-00904: "XML"."EXTRACT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 8
```

Comment: `xml.extract()` is an object method, the alias is required. This is documented at [When Table Aliases Are Required](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28371/adobjbas.htm#CIHBIBEA). However, I don't understand the technical reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably find that this works without using an alias

```
select test_table.xml.extract('(//test/@id)[1]').getStringVal() from test_table;
```

As another comment said, xml.extract is an object method. This means that it is not a function accessible from just anythere, it can only be accessed when dealing with a specific instance of a table object. A simplistic explanation is that the code defining xml.extract is contained somewhere within the code defining a table, so no table, no xml.extract.

As the error message suggests, when it is called on its own, Oracle has no idea what xml.extract is.